# Saving UIPickerView Data to Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView I need to save the users selection to Parse. I've tried a million different things and it just leaves my column blank. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? The information is just not saving to Parse, I know the UIPicker works though because the label updates. I have searched google and stack and can't see anything wrong with my code?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var pickedLabel: UILabel!

var pickerDataSource = ["Car", "Bus", "Train", "Plane", "Boat"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self;
    self.pickerView.delegate = self;
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return self.pickerDataSource.count;
}

   func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return self.pickerDataSource[row]
  }

  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
PFUser.currentUser()?["PickerColumn"] = self.pickerDataSource[row];
  self.pickedLabel.text = "Your choice: \(self.pickerDataSource[row])"
 PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
 }
```

I've also tried this:

```
var pickerSave: String?

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
 {
 pickerSave = pickerDataSource[row]
   self.pickedLabel.text = "Your choice: \(self.pickerDataSource[row])"
  }

 @IBAction func next(sender: AnyObject) {

 PFUser.currentUser()?["pickerColumn"] = pickerSave
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("next", sender:self)
      PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your label is updating then your picker is fine. You issue is the PFUser class. Is PFUser.currentUser() returning a dictionary as you expect? after you set "pickerColumn" can you print out its value on the console?

Does the following work:

```
PFUser.currentUser()?["pickerColumn"] = "1"
PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
```

Those specific lines are what is breaking.

Comment: Hi Andrew yes the picker data prints to log no problem which is why I can't figure it out, it should be just a simple save of the text to parse but its not.                                       '         PFUser.currentUser()?["pickerColumn"] = (pickerDataSource[row])
        print(pickerDataSource[row]) '
        
        PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()

Answer (score 0):

So It looks like you are trying to save the value from the picker into the parse _User class. I wouldn't recommend saving it there anyway. Im assuming you are using a mongoDB and this is a schema issue. So what I would do is make a new class for storing this data.

I would declare it like so.

```
var pickerData = PFObject(className:"PickerData")
@IBAction func next(sender: AnyObject) {

pickerData["user"] = PFUser.current()?
pickerData["data"] = self.pickedLabel.text
pickerData.saveInBackground()
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Jarad I will try that and get back to you.